# Collapsing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm having a fight with UICollectionView to adopt it to my needs.

I'm trying to build a collapsing tag cloud. All elements can dynamically change size based on text inside.

When collection is displayed, I would like to display only first row and hide rest of content.
If there is more content than just for one row I want to show a button as a last item in first row - after selecting it, I will change collection size to fit it's content.

First step:

[image: first step]

After click:

[image: second step]

I was able to achieve desired effect with this code:

```
- (void) updateFrame
{
    if(self.showFull)
    {
        self.showMoreButton.hidden = YES;
        self.bottomConstrain.constant = 0;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.contentSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        self.showMoreButton.hidden = NO;
        self.bottomConstrain.constant = self.originalConstrainValue;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

But button in my case is placed completely outside the collection:

[image: screen]

I'm hitting my head against a brick wall how to make this button to be a part of collection view.
It's the first time I'm playing with UICollectionView and UICollectionViewFlowLayout and it's too complex for me still to understand where would be best spot to put it.

1. One idea I had was to play a button over UICollectionView and position it at the end of first row - but I don't know how to get first row size from collection. With this approach it will be problematic also to cover last item in a row.
2. I think the best will be to put this element as a UICollectionViewCell, but I have no idea how to approach that - how to predict where it will placed and how to hide it later.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. 
Current template project is here:

https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiJjNTg2MGFkNC1mYWYxLTRlMzItOTA1YS1hMWFjOGFkMjMzYjUiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imdya3J1a293c2tpQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9

Comment: I'll also note that you're editing both constraints and frames. You should pick one or the other.

Comment: There is a reason for that - constrains are dependent on parent view frame - take a look and project I shared. I need that to expand my collection view to full size of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve what I wanted with this code (thanks for atreat for suggestion).

I'm estimating which element won't fit in first row, and pushing "More" tag into tags array.
There is some logic also to make sure that More button will fit after last element in this row, if not it's pushed instead of this element. Maybe some will find it usefull.

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        CGFloat collectionWidth = self.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat lastFittingItemRight = 0.0f;
        CGFloat spacingBetweenElements = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing;
        CGFloat sectionInsetLeft = flowLayout.sectionInset.left;
        CGFloat sectionInsetRight = flowLayout.sectionInset.right;

        CGFloat rightEdge = sectionInsetLeft;

        for (int i = 0; i < [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; i++)
        {
            CGSize elementSize = [self collectionView:self.collectionView layout:flowLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
            CGFloat elementWidth = elementSize.width;
            rightEdge += elementWidth;

            if(rightEdge > collectionWidth - sectionInsetRight)
            {
                self.moreButtonIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
                break;
            }

            lastFittingItemRight = rightEdge;
            rightEdge += spacingBetweenElements;
        }

        if(self.moreButtonIndexPath)
        {
            NSString* showMoreText = @"More";
            CGSize moreButtonSize = [self sizeForTagWithText:showMoreText];
            CGFloat rightEdgeMoreButton = lastFittingItemRight + spacingBetweenElements + moreButtonSize.width;

            NSInteger moreButtonIndex = self.moreButtonIndexPath.row;
            if(rightEdgeMoreButton > collectionWidth - sectionInsetRight)
            {
                moreButtonIndex = moreButtonIndex-1;
            }

            [self.tags insertObject:showMoreText atIndex:moreButtonIndex];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting this button as a different cell INSIDE the collection view. Then, in collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: you would check to see if the special item was selected and react accordingly. I would let this button always be the last item in the collection view so you know where it is. When the items have expanded and everything is displayed, make sure you flip your logic and compress the collection view when this special cell is pressed.

You'll need to save some state to do this:

1.The array of tags

2. whether or not the collection view is expanded or not

Once you have this info, you can just flip the bits and reload the collection view section.

Comment: Yes okey - but how can I detect as which element I should place it ? Depends on the previous element size it can be 2nd, 3rd or 4th. So question is how can I estimate where to place it assuming I have defined width for this component and dynamic width for all elements inside.

Comment: If I just place is as a last item, it won't be visible at the beginning because it will be clipped. My biggest problem is to calculate where this item will fit - so it will be visible in first row. Clipping part and expanding is done.

Comment: I think you'll have to iterate through and get the size of each item (call sizeOfCellAtIndexPath or maybe the layoutAttributes of the layout directly). Then once you realize that the special cell will fit perfectly, stop iterating and display that many cells.

Comment: I tried this: - (void) didMoveToSuperview
{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* currentItemAttributes = [flowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(currentItemAttributes.frame));
    }
} But it give me only 0,0 sizes.